# How to make Drupal 6 search result URL use "-" instead of space?

Tags: search, drupal-6

Example of Drupal 6 search result URL is like this:

```
http://www.site.com/search/node/Search for something
```

How to make Drupal 6 search result URL use `-` instead of space? (below is an example):

```
http://www.site.com/search/node/Search-for-something
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, unlike Wordpress, in Drupal, `http://www.site.com/search/node/Search-for-something` means search for `Search-for-something`. There is no way except much hackng in core which many people dont want to.